# how to resolve 500 internal server error in sails js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I use mysql for that.

```
create(req,res){
          Product.create({
               name:req.param('name'),
               qty:req.param('qty')
          }).then(productdata => {
               console.log(productdata)
               return res.ok(productdata);
          }).catch( err => res.serverError(err))
     },
     find(req,res){
          Product.find().then(products => res.ok(products)).catch(err=> res.NotFound(err))
     }
```

Product Controller

```
attributes: {

      name:{
        type:'string'
      },
      qty:{
        type:'integer'
      }
  },
```

Product Model

I get below error for find and create if i call find api then find error and create api then create.

TypeError: Product.find is not a function
at Object.find [as product/find
] (/home/qtech/nodejsproject/crud-project/api/controllers/ProductController.js: 22: 19)
[image]

Comment: Please see my answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018355/typeerrorarticle-find-is-not-a-function-in-sails-js.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the following lines from your controller

```
const Product = require("../models/Product");
```