# TypeError;Article.find() is not a function in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am using sails.js and getting error Articles.find() is not a function. Following is datastore.js

```
    mongodb:{  adapter:require('sails-mongo'),
   url:'mongodb://localhost:27017/articlebase'
 }
```

following is a ArticleController.js

```
const Articles = require("../models/Articles");
module.exports = {
  list: (req,res)=>
  {
    
    Articles.find().exec((err,articles)=>{
    if(err)
    {
      res.send(500,{err:err});
    }
      res.view('articles/articles',{articles:articles});
    });

  }
```

following is models Article.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
title:{
  type:'string'
},
body:{
  type:'string'
},
    
  },
datastore:'mongodb',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from `ArticleController.js`

```
const Articles = require("../models/Articles");
```

Models are included automatically in controller. The following line is automatically included by VSCode to resolve dependencies and not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

ArticleController.js should be modified to be with 'async' and 'await'

```
const Articles = require("../models/Articles");
module.exports = {
  list: async(req,res)=>
  {
    
    await Articles.find().exec((err,articles)=>{
    if(err)
    {
      res.send(500,{err:err});
    }
      res.view('articles/articles',{articles:articles});
    });

  }
```